# Matlab convert consistently sized cells to one matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have a `[100×1]` `cell` looking like:

```
{1x5 cell}
{1x5 cell}
{1x5 cell}
{1x5 cell}
...
{1x5 cell}
```

I would like to obtain instead a `[100×5]` `cell`. How do I do that in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case (contents are not necessarily numbers):

```
result = vertcat(c{:});
```

Example:

```
>> c = {{'a',1}; {'aa','b'}; {3,2}}
c = 
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
>> result = vertcat(c{:})
result = 
    'a'     [1]
    'aa'    'b'
    [ 3]    [2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it consists of numbers only, try this -

```
num2cell(cell2mat(cellarray))
```

Basic idea here is to get all of the data into a double matrix and then convert each of it's elements into elements of a cell array.